# error ENOENT,open '/tmp/45e85388793de' in nodejs

Tags: node.js, gridfs

I am trying to save project and its file in GridFS. I want to save project first and using "_id" of project as metadata for file I want to save file. When i tried so i am getting ENOENT, open '/tmp/45e85388793de' error. here is my code

```
newProject.save(function (err,project) {
            if (err) {
              console.log('save error', err);
            }
             console.log("project added");
             var id=poject._id;
             var filepath    = req.files.file.path;
             var filename    = req.files.file.name;
           var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: filename, metadata:id });
             console.log(filepath);                                                       
             fs.createReadStream(filepath)
             .on('end', function() {

             })
            .on('error', function(err) {
             console.log("error encountered"+err);//ENOENT,open error  
             })
            .pipe(writestream);
            });
```

Why i am getting this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting this error since :

Your file is saved in a temporary location.
When you are inside the callback function your file is removed from that location and you are getting "No such file" error. Path and other variables still exists as part of js and that's why you are able to print them in console.

Solution:
Above(Outside) callback function move your file to some other permanent location using:

```
        fs.rename(req.files.file.path, "./someKnownPath/filename");
```

Keep note of that location. In your callback function use the new location as path and try saving the file in gridfs. Once the file is saved you may delete it file from that location(/someKnownPath/filename).

Answer (score 5):

ENOENT in this context means "No such file or directory." It means the `filepath` you are trying to read with `createReadStream` does not exist.

Comment: hey I am facing the same problem, I know that this error comes when the directory does not exists. As you can see I am writing the file after saving the project since I need to link the file to the project. That's why I have written the code to save the file in callback function of project.save() but it is not working there. If i put the same code outside the .save block the same code works perfectly for same path. (I have displayed the path both inside and outside and they are same)

Answer (score 1):

This error was occuring for me as well. And the reason was temp directory was not in place. After I created manually and gave a try, it worked.

Now I have shifted to creating directory on the fly through node.js itself.